# Variable set in 'if statement' can't be printed outside of it in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

When I assign a variable inside the if statement it doesn't print out at the bottom:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()

#0 monday, 1 tuesday, 2 wednesday, 3 thursday, 4 friday, 5 saturday, 6 su$

if (date == 1 or date == 2): #tuesday wednesday
        location = 'Baltimore'
if (date == 3): #thursday
        location = 'DC'
if (date == 4):
        location = 'Johns Hopkins Cath/Baltimore'
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ifwhile.py", line 13, in <module>
    print location
NameError: name 'location' is not defined
```

Comment: None of your `if` conditions are `True` so location is indeed never defined. You would need to define a default value before your checks e.g. `location = None`

Comment: you need to define `location` outside of the `if`

Comment: Basically what happens if date is a weekend ie 5 or 6?

Comment: Or a Monday, which today is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to consider:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()

#0 monday, 1 tuesday, 2 wednesday, 3 thursday, 4 friday, 5 saturday, 6 su$
whereToGo = {
    0: None
    1: 'Baltimore',
    2: 'Baltimore',
    3: 'DC',
    4: 'Johns Hopkins Cath/Balitmore',
    5: None,
    6: None
}

location = whereToGo[date]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You could even shorten this with `location = whereToGo.get(date)` since `datetime.datetime.today().weekday()` is unlikely to give a number that you've not already asigned to a location or assigned to `None`.

Comment: What would this code be defined as? I know it's not a procedure. Or is it?

Comment: Technically it is a snippet.  You can use it as is, or wrap it in a function:

Comment: Can't than got enough. I'm gonna use this method all the time now.

Answer (score 1):

`None` of your if conditions is `True`, and hence value of `location` is not getting initialized. Because today is *Monday (November 7, 2016)*, which will set value of `date` as `0`. In your code your are not having condition for `0`.

Your code should be like:

```
if (date == 1 or date == 2): #tuesday wednesday
        location = 'Baltimore'
elif (date == 3): #thursday
# ^ I am using elif, because there will only one condition which will be
# True at a time, no need of separate if blocks
        location = 'DC'
elif (date == 4):
        location = 'Johns Hopkins Cath/Baltimore'
else:  # For rest of the weekdays
        location = 'New location'
```